What does “have of you” mean in the following sentence?
“There are things I would have of you. Draw closer. You will learn what they are.” What does “have of you” mean in that sentence? Is “have of” a phrase? Can you also explain the grammar of “have of you”? Thank you.

Three words here contribute to the difficulty because of their somewhat archaic usage.

"Would" is "will" used in the polite conditional. It means "want".

"Of" means "from" here.

"Have" means what it normally does, but this is a little odd combined with that transitional sense of "of", so it might be better translated as "get/receive". This doesn't contribute that much to the archaicness, though. A similar sense might be implied going into a restaurant and being asked, "What'll you have?"


Thus it means "want from you" or "ask from you".

Thank you. Initially my guess was that it meant "I'd have something for you" or "I'd have something that's from you".
